# Como deletar um commit?

Tags: git

Fiz alguns commit's errados e não estou conseguindo deletar um em especifico. Todos que foram feitos após eles foram apagados e era o que eu desejava, usei o comando `git reset --hard + hash` do commit e recebo essa mensagem `HEAD is now at 8932874` Criação do readme. Quando tento dar um `git push --force` recebo a mensagem `Everything up-to-date`. Como faço para apagar o primeiro commit que fiz?

Esse é meu log e quero apagar commit 8932874. Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

```
8932874 (HEAD -> feature/CALONI-65-goiabinha, origin/feature/CALONI-65-goiabinha, master) Criação do readme
a687f69 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merged in feature/CALONI-62-GlofosApp (pull request #22)
43282e7 CALONI-62: Correção de erro onde edição de dados deletava o usuário. Motivo: Comando Bind ainda continha atributo IsVisible ao invés de Enabled.
```

Comment: Costumo usar git rebase -i <commit anterior ao que vc quer apagar> para mudar a história de um repositório. È um canivete suíco que vale a pena aprender, pois serve para apagar um commit da história, mudar a ordem dos commits, editar um commit no meio, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Tente reverter o commit

```
git revert [hash do commit]
```

Você pode tentar também:

```
git reset --hard [hash do commit]
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele ainda mantém esse commit, e eu queria que ele fosse deletado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar o git rebase -i -p HEAD~2

Onde o ~2 é os últimos dois commits.

git log
--para listar os commits.

```
commit 0a6c84980 (HEAD -> hotfix/1, origin/hotfix/1)
Author: Murilo  <murilo@email.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 12 14:16:03 2021 -0300

  commit original

commit dedde93a7498e
Author: Murilo  <murilo@email.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 6 17:21:20 2021 -0300

    Commit duplicado
```

Executo o comando de rebase listando os últimos dois commits.

git rebase -i -p HEAD~2

Vai carregar as seguintes informações;

```
pick dedde93a commit original
pick 0a6c8498 Commit duplicado

# Rebase 72337dee..0a6c8498 onto 72337dee (4 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <commit> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

Marco o commit duplicado como "drop"

pick dedde93a commit original
drop 0a6c8498 Commit duplicado

```
# Rebase 72337dee..0a6c8498 onto 72337dee (4 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <commit> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

Dou um esc e digito :x para salvar e problema resolvido.

Ele vai executar o rebasing e depois só dá um push -f na branch remota pra forçar as atualizações.